# How to show odd and even array value in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I pushed array value but For loop only displayed odd array value only, not showing even array value. i need odd and even array value. please check my for loop. here for loop line   **for(var i = 0; i <= v; i++)**  I refer more exaples but i can't understand. How to solve this issue. coud you please check and let me know.

here my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';

const slider3 = {
  margin: 30,
  responsiveClass: true,
  nav: true,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  navText: ["<i  class='arrow circle left icon'></i>", "<i  class='arrow circle right icon'></i>"],
  responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 2,
        margin:-35,
        responsiveClass: true,
        nav: false,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: false
    },
      400: {
          items: 2,
          margin:-35,
          responsiveClass: true,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
          autoplay: false
      },
      600: {
        items: 2,
        margin:-35,
        responsiveClass: true,
        nav: false,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: false
      },
      
      1000: {
          items: 4,
      }
  },
};
class CollectionTitle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataCollectionTitle: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }
 
    async componentDidMount() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/home";
    fetch(url,requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ dataCollectionTitle: json.sections.collections[0].title});
        // console.log(json)
         })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <span className='sub-heading'>{this.state.dataCollectionTitle}</span>
    );
  }
};








export default class ApiData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }
 
    async componentDidMount() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/home";
    fetch(url,requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.sections});
        
         })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!this.state.data.collections) {
      return null;
    } 
    var v=this.state.data.collections.length;
    const ls = []
      for (var i = 0; i <= v; i++) {
    
    ls.push(  <OwlCarousel className="slider-items owl-carousel" {...slider3}  key={i}>
    {this.state.data.collections[i].stores_list.map((x, i) => 
    <div className="item" key={i}>
     <Link to={x.store_url}><img src={x.image} alt="" className='collection-img'/></Link>
     <img src={x.logo} alt="" className='collection-logo'/>
     <Link to={x.store_url}><h4>{x.store_name}</h4></Link>
     
     <p className='desc'>{x.store_summary}</p>
     <p className='rewards'><span><img src='/images/rewards.png' alt=''></img></span>&nbsp;<span>Cash rewards upto <span className='aed'>AED {x.cashback}</span></span></p>
     <p className='location'><span><img src='/images/location.png' alt=''></img></span>        
      
                   {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                     <span  className='store-location' key={index}>
                      {index === 0 ? <span >{locations.store_location}</span>:
                      index >= 1 ? 
                    <span>,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}</span>:
                    null
                     
                      }
                       </span>
                  ))}
         
                
   
                </p>
   
     </div>
     )}
   </OwlCarousel>
)
    i++;
    }
    return (
      <Grid className='slider-three'>
   <Grid.Column width={1}>      
   </Grid.Column>
   <Grid.Column width={14}>
      <p className='trending'><span>Collections</span></p>
      <p className='collections'><span></span> <CollectionTitle/></p>
    {ls}
   </Grid.Column>
   <Grid.Column width={1}>
   </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
      
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You're for loop is incrementing `i` twice per iteration. The first line of it tells it to increment `i` (`i++`) as well as the last line of it.

Comment: Can you please provide correct for loop? my for loop displayed 0,2,4 array values only, but not showing 1,3,5 array values

Comment: On line 160, you have an extra `i++`. Try removing it.